# multiple step form

Tags: jquery

i am learn to make a multiple step form. i use this jquery code :

```
    $('nav a:last').replaceWith('<a href="#" id="navbtnnext" class="navbtnnext_0">');

    $('form').submit(function(){
        return false;
    });

    $('button.submit_step1, nav a.navbtnnext_0').click(function(){
        $('nav a:first').replaceWith('<a href="#" id="navbtnprev"></a>');
        $('.step1').slideUp();
        $('.step2').slideDown();
        $('nav a#navbtnnext').removeClass('navbtnnext_0').addClass('navbtnnext_1');
    });

    $('button.submit_step2, nav a.navbtnnext_1').click(function(){
        $('.step2').slideUp();
        $('.step3').slideDown();
        $('nav a#navbtnnext').removeClass('navbtnnext_1').addClass('navbtnnext_2');
    });

    $('button.submit_step3, nav a.navbtnnext_2').click(function(){
        $('.step2').slideUp();
        $('.step3').slideDown();
        $('nav a#navbtnnext').removeClass('navbtnnext_2').addClass('navbtnnext_3');
    });
```

when i clicked `nav a.navbtnnext_1` why `.step2` not change into `.step3`?! something wrong with my code? please help me..

here's my html code :

```
       <nav class="grid_12">
            <a id="navbtnprevdisabled"></a>
            <a id="navbtnnextdisabled"></a>
        </nav>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div id="main" class="grid_12" role="main">
            <section id="form">
                <form>
                    <div class="step1">
                        test 1
                        <hr>
                        <button class="submit_step1">Next</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="step2">
                        test 2
                        <hr>
                        <button class="submit_step2">Next</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="step3">
                        test 3
                        <hr>
                        <button class="submit_step3">Next</button>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having those hard-coded buttons in there makes it difficult to scale your form. It would be better if you just used classes instead of ids for the buttons.

This is the most basic example that I can come up with.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.btnNext').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('fieldset').slideUp().next().slideDown();

  });
  $('.btnPrev').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('fieldset').slideUp().prev().slideDown();

  });
});
```

And here is the html to go with it.

```
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Step 1</legend>
      <input /><br/>
      <button class="btnNext">Next</next>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="hidden">
      <legend>Step 2</legend>
      <input /><br/>
      <button class="btnPrev">Previous</button><button class="btnNext">Next</button>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset  class="hidden">
      <legend>Step 3</legend>
      <input /><br/>
      <button class="btnPrev">Previous</button><button class="btnNext">Next</button>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset  class="hidden">
      <legend>Step 4</legend>
      <input /><br/>
      <button class="btnPrev">Previous</button><button class="btnNext">Next</button>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset  class="hidden">
      <legend>Step 5</legend>
      <input /><br/>
      <button class="btnPrev">Previous</button><input type="submit" />
    </fieldset>
  </form>
```

And finaly here is a link to a working example http://jsbin.com/oyoboc/2/edit

Comment: By the way here is a slightly different version with only 1 set of buttons, instead of the buttons being repeated in the fieldsets http://jsbin.com/oyoboc/6/edit

Answer (score 1):

```
$('body').delegate('button.submit_step2, nav a.navbtnnext_1', 'click', function(){
    $('.step2').slideUp();
    $('.step3').slideDown();
});
```

you must use live or delegate when you're dynamically changing classes

Comment: thx for reply @genesis φ :), but this is same like my code before.. i've use ur sugestion like this: `$('section#form').delegate('button.submit_step2, nav a.navbtnnext_1','click', function(){
        $('.step2').slideUp();
        $('.step3').slideDown();
    });`

Comment: @MRWBSN: no it is not as your code before. use my code and try it

Comment: i mean same still not change.. i have put some extra info.. thx for help. :)

Comment: @MRWBSN: one problem is `$('nav a:first').replaceWith('<a href="#" id="navbtnprev">');` - there is no closing </a>

Comment: :D thx for correcting my code.. but that is a prev button and i do not code that button yet until i get solved with this next button first. :) i have follow all your code change the `$('section#id')` into `$('body')`.. okay its work! yey! but skip the first step.. :(

Comment: @MRWBSN: it's not my fault now, and I really have no idea what can be wrong without any code

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a full working simple example, with no need to jQuery.

```js
function shows_form_part(n){
    var i = 1, p = document.getElementById("form_part"+1);
    while (p !== null){
        if (i === n){
            p.style.display = "";
        }
        else{
            p.style.display = "none";
        }
        i++;
        p = document.getElementById("form_part"+i);
    }
}

function submit_form() {
 var sum = parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").value) +
            parseInt(document.getElementById("num2").value) +
            parseInt(document.getElementById("num3").value);
  alert("Your result is: " + sum);
}
```

```html
<body onload="shows_form_part(1)">
<form>
  <div id="form_part1">
    Part 1<br>
    <input type="number" value="1" id="num1"><br>
    <!--form elements 1-->
    <button type="button" onclick="shows_form_part(2)">&raquo;</button>
  </div>
  <div id="form_part2">
    Part 2<br>
    <input type="number" value="2" id="num2"><br>
    <!--form elements 2-->
    <button type="button" onclick="shows_form_part(1)">&laquo;</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="shows_form_part(3)">&raquo;</button>
  </div>
  <div id="form_part3">
    Part 3<br>
    <!--form elements 3-->
    <input type="number" value="3" id="num3"><br>
    <button type="button" onclick="shows_form_part(2)">&laquo;</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="submit_form()">Sum</button>
  </div>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: Thx for answering, it's nice to see another great answer.